# Fix scrollView size in limited height controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

I have a Container view containing an UITableViewController in half height of screen and it is placed at the bottom of screen.

[image]

The problem is: After decelerating upward, i expect the out of bound rows come back to start point of tableView (where they were on load) but they stop moving back on start point of screen top bound! like when tableView is full height! So 3 rows of my sample hides under grey view. (same as situation that size of tableView is full height).

Rows positions are fixed on scrolling downward, then the rows stop moving at tableView start point!!

I found out that `scrollView.contentSize.height` is not same size of container view and equals to screen height (530). I tried to reset it in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:scrollView`, value updated but nothing changes in problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the `contentInset` property on `UITableView`?

Comment: Please post code that you have in relation to the layout parameters of your scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```